# Dynamic Image Variant in Template

Tags: templating, craft3, plugin-imageoptimize

I'm keen to set my image variants dynamically from content editor and not quite sure how I do this in twig.

I have three variants. They are named `imageVariantsThumb`, `imageVariants16by9`, and `imageVariants3by2` in craft.

To render the variant on the image I use the following.

```
{% set optimizedImages = item.itemImage.one().imageVariantsThumb %}
```

Depending on the dropdown selected in the editor (say the values are `thumb`, `16by9` and `3by2`) I want to change the variant name in this line of code. How do I use the value from my drop-down field to change the variant name on the end of the code above?

I have tried defining a variable using the value and replacing `imageVariantsThumb` above but it doesn't work:

```
{% if block.listImageRatio == '16by9' %}
  {% set imageRatio = 'imageVariants16by9' %}
{% endif %}

{% set optimizedImages = item.itemImage.one().imageRatio %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So instead of using the dot syntax `.`, this would be a good place to use the subscript syntax `[]`.

```
{# dot syntax #}
{{ foo.bar }}

{# subscript syntax #}
{{ foo['bar'] }}
```

When you use the subscript syntax to access a variable's attributes, you can safely use variables (by just removing the single quotes surrounding the attribute).

```
{% set bar = 'helloWorld' %}
{{ foo[bar] }}
{# functions just like foo.helloWorld #}
```

So for your example, you would do this:

```
{% if block.listImageRatio == '16by9' %}
    {% set imageRatio = 'imageVariants16by9' %}
{% endif %}

{% set optimizedImages = item.itemImage.one()[imageRatio] %}
```

[(Twig docs)](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#variables)